# changing Colour of dropdown in shiny

Tags: css, r, shiny

I was trying to change the colour of the selectinput dropdown in Shinydashboard, and I wasnt able to change. Here is a simplified example of what I am trying to do

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$style(
    HTML(
      '#FacilityID{ background-color: red;
                  }'  
        )
            ),
selectInput("FacilityID","Enter Facility ID",c("test1","test2")),
               )

server <- function(input, output, session) {

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Through some trial and error, I figured out that adding `'selectize=FALSE'` makes this work. But I am not sure why it is required.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$style("#FacilityID {background-color:blue;}"),
  selectInput("FacilityID","Enter Facility ID",c("test1","test2"), selectize = FALSE)
  )

server <- function(input, output, session) {

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```